# Problems with API return using the Axios library in NextJS

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

I have a problem and I can't solve it in time. Who knows, maybe someone can help me.

I'm testing an application made in DJango Rest Framework (back-end) and NextJS (front-end). The problem I will mention is in NextJS.

I'm trying to make a request using the GET method to my backend to return values from my API. The request itself should return me in JSON format. Using NextJS I made the following model for testing:

**src/pages/plans.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

const Plans = () => {

    async function fetchData() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('/plans', {
                data: null,
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                }
            });
            const data = response.data;
            console.log(data);

        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
    }


    return (
        <button onClick={fetchData}>Buscar Dados</button>
    );
}

export default Plans;
```

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/plans',
        destination: `${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/plans`,
      }
    ];
  },
};
```

**.env**

```
BACKEND_HOST=127.0.0.1
BACKEND_URL=http://websette.localhost:8000
```

When I make the request, the raw value of the 'data' is returned in HTML, as in the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><style data-next-hide-fouc="true">body{display:none}</style><noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true"><style>body{display:block}</style></noscript><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><meta name="next-head-count" content="2"/><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1686444520245"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1686444520245" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1686444520245" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1686444520245" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/plans.js?ts=1686444520245" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1686444520245" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1686444520245" defer=""></script><noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript></head><body><div id="__next"><button>Buscar Dados</button></div><script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1686444520245"></script><script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{}},"page":"/plans","query":{},"buildId":"development","nextExport":true,"autoExport":true,"isFallback":false,"scriptLoader":[]}</script></body></html>
```

I've tried several ways and saw several people on the internet questioning about this problem but no solution. Has anyone managed to resolve this yet?

When I use postman to be able to test the URL of my backend, it works normally, so I think the problem is not in the backend.

Thanks

I need the front-end to return the API values in JSON provided by the back-end

Comment: is `const data = response.data;` the data you want to do something with? because, currently you're doing nothing with it - `saw several people on the internet questioning about this problem` where? which people? what actual problem? also, why are you adding the CORS **response** header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`  in the **request** that is clearly *same origin*?

Comment: Your front end code works fine if you use an API like [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users). Make sur you are calling the correct endpoint, and that the API allows it (regarding cors), etc...

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I believe the problem is in "next.config.js" because the test I did with the tips you passed worked, but when I play the JSONPlaceholder URL in the rewrites of next.config.js it returns HTML instead of JSON